# Division in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, kernel

Is it possible to divide in linux kernel and use double values?
When I tried:

```
typedef struct{ 
    ...
    long long int sbe;
    ...
} connection;

hook_func(){
  connection* found 
  ...
  uint32_t time_misec ..
  uint32_t bytes_diff ..
  ...
  double be = bytes_diff / time_misec;
  found->sbe = be / 2 + found->sbe / 2;
  ...
}
```

I got errors:

```
WARNING: "__fixunsdfsi" [/home/kir/netfilter/hello.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__adddf3" [/home/kir/netfilter/hello.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__floatdidf" [/home/kir/netfilter/hello.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__muldf3" [/home/kir/netfilter/hello.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__floatunsidf" [/home/kir/netfilter/hello.ko] undefined!
```

Comment: At the end I used `do_div()` function for division operations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For most CPU, there is no floating point support in the Linux kernel. The reason is to avoid the high cost of saving FPU registers.

Comment: Even if I'll use this commands:kernel_fpu_begin();
 ...
 kernel_fpu_end() ?

Comment: @caps_lock for some processors yes, I don't know for your specific CPU.

Answer (score 2):

Even if your particular machine supports floating point, and even if you understand how to properly use `kernel_fpu_begin()...end()`, kernel code still should not use floating point code, and your code will probably be rejected if you do.

It appears that your code above is just measuring a simple ratio, something like bytes moved over time? You certainly don't need floating point for something that trivial--just pick a reasonable scale factor and do it in fixed point.

Comment: Yes, you right, I just measure some ratio. But for that I need a division operation even in fixed point. And when I do that I got error: 'WARNING: "__divdi3" [/home/kir/netfilter/hello.ko] undefined!
'

Comment: This is a tiny embedded processor with no division? Or maybe you're linking in the wrong library?

Comment: My Makefile: 
obj-m := hello.o
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
 $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
clean: 
 $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean

Comment: To do integer division on 64-bit values, `#include <linux/math64.h>`, and use one of the functions defined by that header file. There are different functions for different width divisors different width result, signed or unsigned arithmetic, and whether you need a remainder or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to only accumulate the information and
to produce the result (measurement) at the end
using the integer division.

This way you minimize the error to the possible
minimum. The longer you measure the lesser the
approximation error.